# Heat map- adjusting color range

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

```
library(gplots)
shades= c(seq(-1,0.8,length=64),seq(0.8,1.2,length=64),seq(1.2,3,length=64))
 heatmap.2(cor_mat, dendrogram='none', Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, col=redblue(64),  
breaks=shades, key=TRUE, cexCol=0.7, cexRow=1, keysize=1)
```

There is some problem with breaks. Wish to receive help on it.

After running the code I get this error message

```
Error in image.default(1:nc, 1:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 + : must have one more break than colour
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: What is your question? What problems with the break? What do you want help with?

Comment: After running this code i get this error message:
Error in image.default(1:nc, 1:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 +  : 
  must have one more break than colour

This is the problem

Comment: Please add that information to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we don't have cor_mat so we can't try this ourselves, but the problem seems to be what it says on the tin, isn't it? The way heatmap (and generally all functions based on image) works with breaks and a vector of colours, is that the breaks define the points where changes in the value of your data matrix means the colour changes. In short, if `break = c(1,2,3)`, and your `col = c("red", "blue")`:

1. values < 1 will be transparent
2. values >= 1, <= 2 will be plotted as red
3. values > 2, <= 3 will be plotted as blue
4. values > 3 will be transparent

What's going on in your code is that with 'shade' you've supplied a length 3*64 vector to `break`, while `redblue(64)` only gives you 64 colours. Try replacing `redblue(64)` with, say, `redblue(3*64-1)`.